# Generate timed-text synchronised with Text-to-Speech word-by-word?

Tags: autohotkey, text-to-speech, sapi, ttml

How can I generate **timed-text** (e.g. for subtitles) synchronised with Text-to-Speech (**TTS**) word-by-word?

I'd like to do this using the high quality **SAPI5** voices (e.g. those available from IVONA [here](http://visionaid.com/phpincludes/en/support/voices/voices.php)) and that I have used on Windows 10.

On Windows we already have some good free TTS programs:

1. [Read4Me](https://sourceforge.net/projects/read4mecbr/) - open source
2. [Balabolka](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm) - closed source
3. [TTSApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Microsoft's own very basic GUI - currently available [here](http://originaldll.com/file/ttsapp.exe/20409.html) - it seems to date from 2001.

TTSApp can produce audio files in WAV. Balabolka creates MP3 files
 along with synchronised timed-text as LRC files used in Karaoke - BUT only on line-by-line basis NOT word-by-word.
However, both show word-by-word highlighting while they speak aloud on screen - in real time.

If I had some TTS/SAPI5 source code I could simply check the clock every time a new word starts to be generated and write the time and that word to a file.  Does anyone know of any project that exposes that level of programming - so I might start from there?

**UPDATE SEPT 2016**

I've since discovered the TTSApp was reimplemented [using AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77686-text-to-speech-examples-for-autohotkey-v11/) by a certain *jballi* in 2012.

I've adapted that code to append to a text file the time in ms every time the onWord event handler fires.
Still I need to make two passes:

1. a rapid automated pass to save the WAV file and
2. a slow (realtime) pass that creates the timing file.

I am still hoping to find a way to accelerate step 2.

BTW The VisualBasic source appears to be archived [here](https://github.com/emcniece/fps-moba/tree/master/utils/sapi51/Samples/VB/TTSAppVB).

Comment: I was looking around and found [this](http://www.annosoft.com/sapi_lipsync/docs/classsapi__textbased__lipsync_a4.html) which might help. You'll definitely have to call ISpRecoResult::GetResultTimes if you need more accuracy than SPEI_SOUND_START and SPEI_SOUND_END

Comment: Thanks Lesley Gushurst - I'll check out that  SAPI 5.1 Lipsynccode from Annosoft.

Comment: Now I see - the Lipsync program is solving a subtly different problem.  It is producing timed-text yes - but it isn't synthesizing the voice audio at the same time.

Comment: Hmmm... Alright, so if you're already using the Speak call in TTS, have you looked into SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do all of this offline!

You generate a WAV file using SAPI while specifying `DoEvents` - documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#content).

A binary representation of each event (e.g. phoneme/word/sentence) gets appended to the end of the WAV file.  A certain *Hans* documented the WAV/SAPI format in 2009 [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.speech_tech.sdk/VfotWbZ7oDQ).

This can all be done by a simple modification of *jballi*'s 2012 [AutoHotkey version of TTSApp](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77686-text-to-speech-examples-for-autohotkey-v11/)

Basically you replace these lines of code in `Example1GUI.ahk`

```
SpFileStream.Open(SaveToFileName,SSFMCreateForWrite,False)

;-- Set the output stream to the file stream
SpVoice.AllowAudioOutputFormatChangesOnNextSet:=False
SpVoice.AudioOutputStream:=SpFileStream

;-- Speak using the given flags
SpVoice.Speak(Text,SpeakFlags)
```

with the following:

```
SpFileStream.Open(SaveToFileName,SSFMCreateForWrite,True) ;-- DoEvents 

;-- Set the output stream to the file stream
SpVoice.AllowAudioOutputFormatChangesOnNextSet:=False
SpVoice.AudioOutputStream:=SpFileStream

if not Sink ;-- DoEvents label
  {
    ComObjConnect(SpVoice, "On")
    Sink:=True
  }

;-- Speak using the given flags
SpVoice.Speak(Text,SpeakFlags|SVSFlagsAsync|SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak)
```